# Can I add more than three web.config transformations?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

Is it possible to add a fourth web.config transformation with Visual Studio?
I have three transformations:
[image]

But when I want to add one the option in contextual menu is disabled:
[image]

(It is in French, it means "Add Configuration transformations")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the top of your screen where you change it from "Debug" to "Release" etc. Open the drop down, go to "Configuration Manager" in the "Active solution configuration:" list drop it down and select "New".

When you've added the new one(s), you may need to refresh your project or close VS and re-open, then when you right-click a the web.config you will get the new configurations in the list.

Hope that makes sense. :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I don't look in this side!

Comment: I had to unload and then load the project before I could add configuration transforms.